# Open text file by tapping a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have some basic questions. During launching, my app is looking for text files created in application and adds views that represent these files. Simple. I have information about file name, location etc.

Now I want to open a file by taping on a view. Does someone know the best way to open file? I can set Tag property of a view by adding file path. I can subview the UIView class, but don't know which solution is the best :)

Just how to open the file?

Comment: What do you mean by opening a file? Do you want to launch default application associated with the text file (e.g. TextEdit) OR open the file in Objective-C and read its contents?

Comment: But my problem is not solved... By Opening a file I meant: In MainView I am presenting stored text files. To achieve this I'm subclassing a UIView (one file in MainView is presented as one instance of my subclass - rectangle with file name on it). And my subclass of UIView contains details about file like file name or file path. Now I want to open new xib with text edit and passed text to this text edit...

Answer (score 1):

You could use enum and set tag to UIView or UIView subclasses (UIButton), and use switch-case to check if the correct view was tapped.

To manipulate with files use NSFileManager: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: My approach was wrong. I should implement UIGesture recognizer in view... It was to simple :)